# Python error in telegram bot when editing a message

Tags: python, py-telegram-bot-api, telebot

I see error:
`(async_telebot.py:529 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "59754269930"`
In my code, I handle the callback:

```
select_item = {}

async def show_items(message, is_update):
    with con.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY id ASC')
        items = cursor.fetchall()
        con.commit()
    item = items[select_item[message.from_user.id]]
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=8)
    btn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('one', callback_data='item1')
    btn2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('two', callback_data='item2')
    markup.add(btn1, btn2)
    msg = 'Test'
    if is_update == False:
        await bot.send_photo(chat_id=message.chat.id, photo=urllib.request.urlopen(item['image']), caption=msg, reply_markup=markup)
    else:
        await bot.edit_message_media(chat_id=message.chat.id, message_id=message.id, media=types.InputMedia(type='photo', media=open('start.jpg', 'rb')))
        await bot.edit_message_caption(chat_id=message.chat.id, message_id=message.id, caption='edit')

@bot.message_handler()
async def get_user_text(message):
    if message.text == 'Items':
        if select_item.get('message.from_user.id') is None:
            select_item[message.from_user.id] = 0
        await show_items(message, False)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
async def callback(call):
    if call.message:
        if call.data == 'item1':
            await show_items(call.message, True)
```

And I don’t understand what the problem is, I’m a beginner, I need to process for each user the choice of the element that he will now scroll through

Checked data but it's ok

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
  if call.data == 'item1':
            await show_items(call, True)
```

and

```
await bot.edit_message_media(chat_id=message.message.chat.id, message_id=message.message.id, media=types.InputMedia(type='photo', media=open('start.jpg', 'rb')))
        await bot.edit_message_caption(chat_id=message.message.chat.id, message_id=message.message.id, caption='edit')
```

I mixed up the object, it referred to the message of the bot and not the user